# Android: onActivityResult is not getting called for different resultcodes

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am starting an activity with startActivityForResult like this

```
@Override
public void onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("time",time);
    bundle.putInt("fragmentId",1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddEventActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
```

and in AddEventActivity i add fragments depending on the fragment id.The first fragment add events and second fragment delete events.onAddEvent and onDeleteEvent i setResult with appropriate data like this

```
@Override
public void onAddEventClicked(Bundle bundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(1,intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void eventDelete(Events event) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("deleteEvent",event);

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(2,newIntent);
    finish();
}
```

OnActivityResult code is something like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == 1 && data != null){
        if(requestCode == 1){

        }
    }else if(resultCode == 2){

    }
}
}
```

Now onActivityResult is getting called onAdding event but not on deleting event.eventDelete method is getting called but it is not triggering onActivityResult.What could be the problem?Thankyou.

**UPDATED**
I put a debug at first line in onActivityResult but debugger doesn't stop there.

Comment: are you sure `eventDelete` is called at all?

Comment: yes i have checked with debugger..

Comment: post your called activity code (`AddEventActivity`)

Comment: @pskink : i combined both the add and delete event methods into one callback and it worked..anyways thanks a lot for your time..

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

here 1 is your `requestCode`

```
setResult(1,intent);
```

here 1 is your `resultCode`

you are setting same `resultcode` for  Two events

change your `onActivityResult` to

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == 1) {    //add event
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (data != null) {

                if (data.getExtras().containsKey("deleteEvent")) {

                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode == 2) { //delete event
        //write code
    }
}
```

Comment: nope its not working.i put a debug at first line in onActivityResult but debugger doesn;t stop there..

Comment: did u call it like: `setResult(2 ,newIntent);` in your delete event ?

Comment: i updated the question.But alteast it should debug at the very first line even if the inside logic is wrong..

Comment: adding two different `resultCode`s doesn't change anything, OP's problem is that `onActivityResult` is not called at all

Comment: @pskink  `doesn't change anything` i hate to disagree...op was using the same resultcode  for two events  so i think that's the problem...one gets called while the other doesn't  ..if  `onActivityResult` not getting called for second event problem lies somewhere else other than the code op provides..

Comment: @pskink u r welcome to share ur thought ...other than grilling other answer

Comment: if u want to differentiate between the events with same `sameRequestCode` u should use `resultcode` as different

Comment: the result is used for telling if the called activity  was successful or not, if not, you can use *different* result error codes, but if it was successful you should use `RESULT_OK` and the `Intent data` holds the details - most likely via `data.getAction()` method - "String getAction ()
Retrieve the general action to be performed, such as ACTION_VIEW. The action describes the general way the rest of the information in the intent should be interpreted -- most importantly, what to do with the data returned by getData()."

Comment: try to set second intent  result using: `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)`

Answer (score -1):

you should add RESULT_OK and validate this resultCode:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("returndata");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

after this, u need add the validation in your onActivityResult method...

```
     if(requestCode == CODE_REQUEST){
     if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        //do something here
      }{
       //catch cancel result
   }
    }
```